# How to calculate apache airflow sensor total execution time

Tags: airflow, sensors, statsd

```
sensor_job = PythonSensor(
            task_id='sensor_id',
            python_callable=call_jobsensor,
            poke_interval=10,
            timeout=7 * 60,
            mode='reschedule',
        )        


def call_jobsensor():
    # start timer
    # do something
    # stop timer
```

**Use Case** - In this example, I am trying to capture the total time taken to complete the sensor job. Here completing means either it should timeout or the sensor returns true.
If I go by the traditional method, It will return the time information in small chunks(every time the sensor calls this function) but what I need is the total time.

Is there any method or support from Airflow or Statsd that I can utilize here? Or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are using Airflow v2:

You can use the airflow database backend to get the duration of tasks in a DAG.

This assumes you have set up an [airflow database backend](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html) and configured the default `airflow_db` connection with your host, schema, username and password.

Depending on what database you are using, you'll need to install the relevant provider.

You can view the documentation for `apache-airflow-providers-mysql` [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/index.html).

And the documentation for `apache-airflow-providers-postgres` [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/index.html).

You'll need to globally install the provider to the airflow environment.

The `task_instance` table contains the duration that each task took to run. There isn't an easy way to see the schemas of the tables, one way is to use a 3rd party tool (such as DBeaver) and connect to the database and inspect the tables + schemas.

An example DAG for accessing using PostgreSQL is (if using MySQL just swap the import for the `MySQLHook`):

```py
import pendulum

# from airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql import MySqlHook  # install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook  # install apache-airflow-providers-postgres
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(start_date=pendulum.yesterday(tz="Europe/London"))
def test_dag():
    @task()
    def test_duration_task():
        # or a PythonSensor operator...
        from time import sleep
        sleep(3)
        
    @task()
    def run_query(**context):
        postgres_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="airflow_db")
        records = postgres_hook.get_records(sql="select duration from task_instance where task_id='test_duration_task' order by end_date desc")
        print(f"task duration for test_duration_task = {records[0][0]}")

    test_duration_task() >> run_query()


test_dag_failure_dag = test_dag()
```

The log output of `run_query` is:

```
[2022-06-10, 19:57:59 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID '***_db' for task execution.
[2022-06-10, 19:57:59 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - task duration for test_duration_task = 3.200903
[2022-06-10, 19:57:59 UTC] {python.py:173} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
```

Comment: This doesn't help in the case of Sensors. Since the duration attribute inside the task_instance table will be overridden every time the sensor is called and I will only get the last run duration of the sensor instead of complete time (including waiting period). Thanks for the effort though